# RANK.EQ and RANK.AVG seem to have a bug

Tags: excel

RANK.EQ and RANK.AVG seem to have the same annoying bug:

- they confuse FALSE with zero.

In my first formula below, RANK.EQ works fine:

- when finding a non-numeric value (FALSE in this case) it returns #N/A.

However, if my range happens to have a zero (second formula), RANK.EQ confuses FALSE with zero,

- it returns a value when it shouldn't.

I have not found a satisfactory workaround for this bug.

The only workaround I can think of is reading the returned array, and replacing any values where the original values are FALSE.

Any other ideas?

[image]

Comment: just to point out both functions have the same behavior if you enter the same input value. You last value for the second set of value is not the same. In the first set you have `-1` and in the second `0`.  If you use the same set of value you get the same result. Another thing is that according to [RANK.EQ documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/284858ce-8ef6-450e-b662-26245be04a40) it states non numeric values are ignored in **Ref** input argument, which is not the case for the second set, but it happens in both result using the same input.

Comment: David,   if I use the same set of values, and the formula is the same, of course that I get the same result, it seems obvious to me; the proble is that, in the second example, according to the documentation, any non-numeric values should be ignored, and they are not; the FALSE value in the second example returns a "4" because it confuses FALSE with zero, and they are not the same; this i why I consider that there is a bug with the RANK functions